# Excel - How to persist function in column when row data is cut or deleted?

Tags: excel

is is possible in Excel to have some sort of fixed function defined for a entire column? This function needs to persist when a row is deleted, and it needs to 'exist' when new row data is added...

**So in the example below, If I cut row 1 to row 3 (so the worksheet is empty), I want the 'new' row 1 to have the function in column D already defined (which is actually: multiply the value from C from the same row with 10)... Is this possible?**

```
-----------------------------------------
|    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
-----------------------------------------
|    1    |    1    |    1    |=C1 * 10 |  --- ROW 1
-----------------------------------------
|    1    |    1    |    1    |=C2 * 10 |  --- ROW 2
-----------------------------------------
|    1    |    1    |    1    |=C3 * 10 |  --- ROW 3
-----------------------------------------
|         |         |         |         |
-----------------------------------------
|         |         |         |         |
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2007 this type of functionality is built in, so long as the data is marked as a table.

Select your data range and click on '**Insert - Table**' alternately **Ctrl-l** or **Ctrl-t**

Add a new column heading and your formula next to the last column of data.  The table will automatically expand to include the new column.  It will automatically copy the formula down to all rows.

Any new rows added will automatically have the formula included.

Comment: A yes there is, tables are not very intuitive ;)

Comment: They are called Lists in 2003, renamed tables in 2007 and they have been greatly improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the cell with the function in it, then click the column header (to select all of it) that you want the function to persist in, then right click - paste special - formuals, that should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not pasting... i'm cutting?

Comment: Write the function at least once, then paste it into every cell of the column using paste special. Then when you cut row 1 and paste into 3 the function will be there already.

Comment: Again: I'm NOT pasting, only cutting

Comment: I need to cut the formula, because I need the value in another workbook (where I AM pasting)..... I think you should lay off the pills ;)

Comment: So you are pasting :)... any way, am totally lost.